# Developer options switch is disabled, hence not able to turn it on

Tags: usb-debugging

I'm having a Samsung Galaxy S5 Android phone. All these days I was able to debug apps using USB debugging from the Developer options menu in my phone. But suddenly I noticed the switch in the developer options screen is disabled ([See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSZzD.png)). Only Running services item is enabled in the Developer options screen.

Note: I have a "Software Update" system warning, which is an update that is already automatically downloaded but not yet installed. I'm wondering if the developer options is disabled because of this system

Has anyone faced the same problem ?
Do you know what to do to enable the switch, so that I can turn on the usb debugging ?

Thank you.

Comment: So you can't enable 'Developer options' in the blue/cyan header area to enable 'USB Debugging'?

Comment: Yes, that switch is just disabled. I'm not able to slide it on or off.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung phone and if I turn that switch off, the options just disappear and to re-enable them, I have to tap build number 7 times again. It basically makes it look like I have never even tried to enable developer options. Probably, if you tap build number 7 times, it will get it fixed.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found from [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/125443) that some recently added app might be cauing the security issue.

Hence I uninstalled my corporate app that I installed prior to getting that greyed out issue, and that fixed that problem, I'm now able to slide the switch on/off in Developer Options screen.